# Keeping up to date with OSM changes in pgRouting

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I'm working on a routing application using OSM and pgRouting.  I'm only interested in a subset of data, mostly North America (performance was difficult for large amounts of data, so don't want to use the whole world).  I want to be able to keep up with updates to OSM data, but I haven't seen any place that provides a smaller changeset then for the whole world.  Is reimporting the data every time I want to update the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called diff updates. You have two options ..

1. Apply the [Diffs](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/minute/) from PlanetOSM and then [remove](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Stephankn/knowledgebase#Cleanup_of_ways_outside_the_bounding_box) the imported geometry that are outside of your bounding box
2. Use the Geofabrik Extracts for [North America](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html) and apply the Geofabrik [diffs](http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america-updates/) which are updated daily.

I do both, 3 minute diff updates for the planet and daily diff updates for the Philippines, in different databases. I use the Philippine subset for pg_routing, the planet is too large.

Comment: I hadn't seen the diffs mentioned anywhere on Geofabrik, thanks! Can you use osm2pgrouting on those daily diffs?

Comment: How did you load you database? with osm2pgsql? if so apply them with that. the blue link worded "diffs" is linked to the download directory on Geofabrik which is where the diffs come from.

Comment: I loaded the database originally with osm2pgrouting, I just hadn't seen the .osc files before.  Do you know they be loaded with osm2pgrouting ?

Comment: No The cannot with PgRouting. The only package so far that I know of is osm2pgsql, which is what we use ..

Answer (score 2):

The term for what you want to do is *incremental updating* so I recommend that you look at the [Osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) page where it says:

> osm2pgsql has two main modes of running - normal and slim mode.
>
> It is highly recommended to run osm2pgsql in slim mode. Some important
>   features (including incremental updates (planet diffs, the initial
>   load to populate the track tables, and proper evaluation of
>   multipolygons) only work in slim mode.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody needs differ files from Geofabrik website one can use my "getdiff" program for Linux from my [github repository](https://github.com/waelhammoudeh/getdiff)